# How to use Keyboard keys event in HtmlUnitDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, headless

I am trying to use Headless testing using HTMLUnitDriver library.

My code with keyboard keys events working fine with real browser but same code is not working when using HTMLUnitDriver headless testing.

I tried below option-

//Using Action

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

// using Keyboard

```
Keyboard keyboard = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getKeyboard();
keyboard.pressKey(Keys.ENTER);
```

// using sendkeys

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(search)).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

With all the above code I not getting any error but also not performing any key event.

Comment: [Here's a simple sample code snippet explain briefly found in Stake-overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169598/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through Robot class in Java.awt API.

below is the code snippet you can use for opening a new tab in chrome. (Cntrl+T)

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } 
            catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);  
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

Comment: Not working when chrome mode is --headless..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robot object to work with Keyboard keys,as i have used the same in Browser Authentication to pass Username and password ,PFB

```
Robot rb = new Robot(); 
StringSelection user = new StringSelection("RajKuc");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(user, null);

//User which replace with entered user name //Copy Username data using
Ctrl+v as below `rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);`

rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
```